# How to remove a draggable item upon button click for undo?

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop, undo

I have 2 draggable items. These 2 draggable items can be dragged to any of the droppable divs. However, when i click on the undo button, i need to remove the draggable items accordingly in the order of when it was placed. Like im sure you know how undo button works. I wonder if i can undo draggable items from the divs?

The correct answer should be when drag1 item is in div1 - so when it is in div1, upon clicking the undo button, it has to detect whether drag1 is inside, but instead if drag2 and drag1 is both inside div1, it will remove only the drag2 inside div1.

Jquery:

```
$("#drag1").draggable({
  helper: 'clone'

 });
 $("#drag2").draggable({
     helper: 'clone'
});

$("#undo").click(function () {
  $('.div1').html("");
});
```

Html:

```
<img id="drag1" style="width:1.25vw; height:1.5vw;" name="image"  src="images/equation1_3.png" draggable="true">

<img  id="drag2" style="width:1.20vw; height:1.55vw;"  name="image" src="images/equation1_2.png" draggable="true" >

<div class="boxFirstCol box1 b1 box" id="div1" style="width:5.5vw; height:3vw; "> 
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement undo on the last action only? for example if drag1 is dragged to item2 and drag2 is dragged to item1 on button click, both should go back (in other words, the UI must RESET)?

Comment: im trying to keep on removing the last action, so it keeps on removing until they can no longer undo which means everything is back to square 1 again

Comment: Are you using a `droppable` in your html as well?

Comment: yes, i am using droppable method with jquery

Comment: Which element is the droppable element?

Comment: the droppable element is div1